# Why can't the internal argument of "matter" raise?

Tags: verbs, clauses, unaccusative

The internal arguments of unaccusative verbs in English must raise to subject position to obtain case and satisfy the EPP. For example, verbs like *melt, fall, die, arrive,* etc. must have their internal arguments raise:

1. He died.
2. He fell.
3. He arrived.

Expletives are not compatible with most of these verbs in English and not many people nowadays accept the ones that are. They sound pretty archaic:

1. ?There arrived a man
2. ?There spread a disease
3. *There fell a man
4. *There died a man

*Matter* seems to be an unaccusative verb based on the semantics (especially the volitionality) of the subject; however, the internal argument of the verb is able to remain in object position, as in the following sentence:

5. It doesn't matter which one you choose.
6. [Which one you choose]<sub>1</sub>   doesn't matter *t*<sub>1</sub>.

Is it because the internal argument of *matter* is a clause and that clauses do not need to obtain case? I think it is, because *matter* can also take a DP complement and DPs require case, which causes them to obligatorily raise. This is why when *matter* takes a DP complement, the expletive is ungrammatical:

7. *It matters him

Are there any more such unaccusative verbs that take clausal complements and can take expletive *it*?